# Material UI css load order

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am having hard time understanding how I should structer my project. 
I am using react with material UI and css modules.
Problem is that god knows why, all styling from MUI loads at the bottom of the header same as css module styling.
After some research I found two solutions:

1. Use !important inside css modules which is terrible.
2. Changing the injection order https://material-ui.com/guides/interoperability/#css-modules

Problem with the second one is that it would be terrible tedieouse in a multi component project where every time you introduce a new component you have to load it manually as in the example. Am I missing something obvious? Do you have any ideas how to easier change the load order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be misunderstanding something in the example. There isn't anything you need to do on a per-component basis to change the load order.
The steps are as follows:

1. In your `index.html` add a comment like `<!-- jss-insertion-point -->` into the head where you would like the jss CSS to be inserted.

2. In your `index.js` (or somewhere at or near the top of your rendering hierarchy) create the jss configuration to indicate the name of the insertion point comment:

```
import JssProvider from "react-jss/lib/JssProvider";
import { create } from "jss";
import { jssPreset } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const jss = create({
  ...jssPreset(),
  // We define a custom insertion point that JSS will look for injecting the styles in the DOM.
  insertionPoint: "jss-insertion-point"
});
```

3. Wrap your top-level element in the `JssProvider` to put those configurations in play (no component-specific steps):

```
function App() {
  return (
    <JssProvider jss={jss}>
      <div className="App">
        <Button>Material-UI</Button>
        <Button className={styles.button}>CSS Modules</Button>
      </div>
    </JssProvider>
  );
}
```

I've created a CodeSandbox similar to the one pointed at by the Material-UI documentation except that this one uses the create-react-app starting point, so the dependencies are simpler.

[image: Edit r5o1vw5po]

Comment: I had same problem. I did the same way you mentioned above. Even though my CSS injection order is perfect still I need to use !important to override material ui styles. is there any workaround to  avoid !important

Comment: @M14 Create a separate question with the relevant code (preferably with a CodeSandbox that reproduces the problem) and reference this question and point out exactly what isn’t working as desired.

Comment: @M14 You should be able to use my CodeSandbox from this question as a starting point for creating a simple reproduction of your problem.

Comment: If you are using a custom Head component, you can implement the first step as:
`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: \`<!-- jss-insertion-point -->\`, }} />`

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Material-UI documentation](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#css-injection-order), you should add a `<StylesProvider/>` component, which wraps your component tree.

```
import { StylesProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

<StylesProvider injectFirst>
  {/* Your component tree.
      Styled components can override Material-UI's styles. */}
</StylesProvider>
```

If `injectFirst` is set (and `true` of course), the Material UI style tags will be injected first in the head (less priority)

Answer (score 1):

In version 5 MUI changed the import and some components became deprecated.
By default, the style tags are injected **last** in the `<head>` element of the page. They gain more specificity than any other style tags on your page e.g. CSS modules, styled components.
Not in the documentation, but the `StyledEngineProvider` component has an `injectFirst` prop to inject the style tags first in the head (less priority):

```js
<StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
 <MUIThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  {children}
 </MUIThemeProvider>
</StyledEngineProvider>
```