# Override Material UI Tab Indicator Emotion Styled

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, emotion, css-in-js

Trying to figure out how to override the styles of the tabs indicator using styled from Emotion. I am not sure how to access nested classes. This is what I have, but it isn't getting me there:

```js
const StyledTabs = styled(Tabs)(
  {
    classes: {
      indicator: {
        background: 'black',
      },
    },
  }
);
```

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: I never worked with emotion, but I think the problem is that you can't pass `{ background: 'black'  }` as object styles to indicator, but rather a class name. Can you try something like `css\`background: black;\`` instead of  `{ background: 'black'  }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple issues. `styled` from Emotion only supports generating a single class name per usage. It doesn't provide any support for the `classes: {indicator: {styles}}` structure in your example.

Below is a syntax that allows you to use `styled` to provide a class name for the "indicator" class of `Tabs`:

```
const StyledTabs = styled(({ className, ...other }) => {
  return <Tabs {...other} classes={{ indicator: className }} />;
})({
  backgroundColor: "black"
});
```

However, this does not work completely robustly because the `<style>` element for the Emotion styles does not consistently occur after the `<style>` elements from JSS (used for Material-UI's styling) in the `<head>` of the document. I'm not sure how to alter the insertion point for Emotion's styles, but you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53868775/material-ui-css-load-order/53872551#53872551) about how to change the insertion point for JSS. I've included this approach in my sandbox below.

Here's a sandbox that shows this working:

[image: Edit Tabs indicator emotion]

Another syntax option is the following which will allow you to control more than one Tabs class:

```
const StyledTabs = styled(({ className, ...other }) => {
  return <Tabs {...other} classes={{ root: className, flexContainer: "flexContainer", indicator: "indicator" }} />;
})({
  "& .indicator": {
    background: "black"
  },
  "& .flexContainer": {
    flexDirection: "row-reverse"
  }
});
```

[image: Edit Tabs indicator emotion]

Comment: This helps a ton! Great explanation. Thank you!

Comment: how would I go about adding things to this style object. such as the flexContainer?

Comment: I've added to my answer. Also, you may want to chime in here: https://twitter.com/olivtassinari/status/1107618920545030144. Olivier is asking for input from styled-components users, but emotion/styled presents the same difficulties.

Comment: Does having one of these variables in the same file conflicts? I am trying to do this for Tab as well and trying to get the textColorInherit or selected to work, but the styles don't seem to take.

Comment: Having more than one in the same file shouldn't be an issue. Please share a sandbox showing an example of the problem.

Comment: Here is the codePen:

https://codesandbox.io/s/k2w78lnlkr

I added a StyledtTab with some styles and they dont seem to take.

Comment: In the documentation, pay attention to "Styles applied to the root element if...". This means the class is not on a descendant element but on the same element as the root class, so you need to use `"&.selected"` (no space) instead of `"& .selected"`.

Comment: You've been super helpful. Thanks a ton!